# Matlab prevent axis resizing between plots in a loop

Tags: matlab, octave

OK so I've got a plotting loop which plots an expanding and contracting object. The data 
for each frame is in a huge matrix.

I've found the min and max values of each frame for the x,y,z coordinates of the object. So I've got the limiting planes of the object's expansion reach.

The plotting loop has several plotting commands. The first line of the loop is clf:

```
for frame = 1:N    %N is the number of frames
  clf;
  hold on;
  axis([minX maxX minY maxY minZ maxZ]);
  % Plotting commands...(skipped here)
  drawnow;
end
```

The axes change periodically. They will not change between successive frames but say at frame 300 they will change and then will change back at say frame 700 and do that again.

I've checked with get(gcf, 'CurrentAxes') and the values are different. Not sure why. The axis limits are constant.

EDIT: With some data set this doesn't happen but with some the axes change periodically as described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `axis` command after the plotting commands.

Comment: Thanks. I had it after the plotting commands but I must have accidentally moved it. Didn't realize it's causing that problem. I've put it just before drawnow and it works.